# Add class to body for each scrolling based on section ID

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have a page layout like this.

```
<body>
  <section id="s1">...</div>
  <section id="s2">...</div>
  <section id="s3">...</div>
</body>
```

I need to add class to body tag whenever the `<section>` meet the top by scrolling. like `<body class="s1">` for `#s1` section and `<body class="s2">` for `#s2`. How this can be done using jquery?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want:

http://jsbin.com/tabolida/1/edit?html,js,output

```
var bodyEl = $("body");
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $("section").each(function() {
        var el = $(this),
            className = el.attr("id");
        if (el.offset().top < scrollTop) {
            bodyEl.addClass(className);  
        } else {
            bodyEl.removeClass(className);
        }
    });
});
```

In short: while scrolling, the `offset().top` of every section is checked against the scroll position of the window. If it is lower, a CSS class is added to the body; if it's higher, the CSS is removed. This could result in your body element having multiple classes:

```
<body class="s1 s2">
```

...which is solved by CSS as long as both classes have the same precedence 'points'. Also, if you have a lot of `section`s in your page, performance might suffer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up

```
$(window).scrollTop() and $(element).offset()
```

and compare those two in

```
$(window).scroll( function() { } );
```

There you can see which element is closest to the top border of the window, and act according to that.

Is that what you need?